# 1st law of thermodynamics formulation in terms only of internal energy

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm starting in the field of thermodynamics and I'm seeing that in the formulation of the first law, we only take care of the internal energy but not in the energy of the whole system. Let me explain:

The energy of a system can be written as $E_{system}=K_{system}+U_{system}$ when dealing with a system of particles, $K_{system}=\sum K_i=\sum\frac{1}{2}m_iv_i^2$ and $U_{system}=\sum U_i$. But we know that $K_{system}=\frac{1}{2}m_Tv_{cm}^2+\sum\frac{1}{2}m_iu_i^2$, where $m_T$ is the total mass of the system, $v_{cm}$ is the speed of the center of mass, and $u_i$ is the speed of the $i$-th particle with respect to the center of mass. This means that the internal energy can be expressed as $\mathcal{U}=\sum\frac{1}{2}m_iu_i^2+\sum U_i$, and so the energy of a system $E_{system}=\frac{1}{2}m_tv_{cm}^2+\mathcal{U}$.

When aplying the conservation of energy principle to the system when no heat is considered, $W_{ext}=\Delta E_{system}=\Delta\left(\frac{1}{2}m_tv_{cm}^2\right)+\Delta\mathcal{U}$, which means that external work produces changes both in the internal and center of mass energy.

Now let's take heat in consideration. A similar expression may be written: $W_{ext}+Q=\Delta E_{system}=\Delta\left(\frac{1}{2}m_tv_{cm}^2\right)+\Delta\mathcal{U}$, but comparing it with the first law of thermodynamics, there is an extra term, $\Delta\left(\frac{1}{2}m_tv_{cm}^2\right)$, because, as far as I know, the first law of thermodynamics is formulated as $W_{ext}+Q=\Delta\mathcal{U}$.

My question is why we don't write the term $\Delta\left(\frac{1}{2}m_tv_{cm}^2\right)$ in the first law of thermodynamics? Is it that I have misconceptions in some of the concepts used here, or is it that, for example, in thermodynamics we always work in a reference frame moving with the center of mass of the system, making $v_{cm}=0$ always, or what's the issue I'm having here?

Thank you.

Comment: The more general form of the first law includes macroscopic kinetic energy and gravitational potential energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general form of the first law for a closed system includes the kinetic energy (KE) and potential energy (PE) of its center of mass (COM) with respect to an external frame of reference. I like to call this the system's "external" KE and PE to contrast it with the "internal" molecular KE and PE of the system with respect to the COM reference frame. The total change in system energy is then the sum of its internal and external energy.

The figure below is my attempt to illustrate the difference. (Note: only shows gravitational PE as the external PE).

Hope this helps.

[image]